# mappend! can't append element to the list if the list is empty?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(require racket/mpair)

(define (bld-mlst . args)
  (list->mlist args))

(define mlst-my (bld-mlst))
mlst-my

(mappend! mlst-my (list->mlist (list 100)))
mlst-my

(define mlst-my2 (bld-mlst 2))

(mappend! mlst-my2 (list->mlist (list 100)))
mlst-my2
```

it will print out:

```
(mcons 100 '())
'()
(mcons 2 (mcons 100 '()))
(mcons 2 (mcons 100 '()))
```

The first and third line is just the return value of the mappend! Note the second line and fourth line! We can see that the second line is `'()`, which means that mappend! does not change the `mlst-my`! While when the `mlst-my2` is not empty, the `mappend!` works fine. 
**Question:**
Then How to make the mappend! to still side effect the mlist when the mlist is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't! The empty list is a singleton, immutable object. It has no slots (car or cdr) that you can change. But you can do this:

```
(set! mlst-my (mappend! mlst-my (list->mlist (list 100))))
```

That is, you `set!` your variable to `mappend!`'s return value.

---

To understand all that, understand how singly linked lists work. It comprises *cons cells* (or *dotted pairs*), which each have two slots (traditionally named `car` and `cdr`). The `car` slot points to the value, and the `cdr` points to the next cons/pair.

So, a list like `(1 2 3)` has three conses:

```
#0=(1 . #1#)
#1=(2 . #2#)
#2=(3 . ())
```

The way `append!` works is to find the last cons (the one whose `cdr` is pointing to `()`), and change its `cdr` to point to the list you're appending.

If your list is empty, though, it has no conses, and therefore it has nothing to change. Empty lists are always immutable.

Comment: if we test the empty list `'()`like this: `(mlist? '())`, it says `#t`, then why can't mutate it! It is so weird!

Comment: @freezdom: `mlist?` simply tells you if all the contained conses are mutable. Since an empty list has no conses, that statement ("are all conses mutable") is true, in terms of there being no conses that are immutable.

Comment: Nice explanation, but the append! does not work on the empty list is still bad! (My head is still wondering whether there is any other workarounds)

Comment: @freezdom: Absent using `set!`, or a box, or something like it, there are no workarounds. An empty list is always immutable, no exceptions.

Comment: @freezdom: Are you familiar with languages like C or Java? What you're asking for is to mutate NULL so that it's not NULL any more. Same issue.

Comment: @John: yeah, in that sense, it is obvious.

Comment: @John,Chris: (oh, can't edit what I wrote before)... the `null` example is obvious and good: the cons linklist ends with `null` which is indeed like the empty list.

Comment: @freezdom: Actually, in Common Lisp, the empty list is named `nil`. In Scheme, though, it's just called `()` which can look deceptively like non-empty lists. (You only have 5 minutes to edit a comment.)